# Save signature on user's account, not device, in Office 365

Tags: outlook, vbscript, office365

This issue goes so far over my head I am effectively looking at pretty letters, numbers and symbols on a page.

We have used a visual basic script for applying and updating our email signatures for roughly 10 years. I have only been with the company 18 months so this is something I got shown how to run when I first started, but all I edit it for is to repoint to an updated web hosted image every now and again.

The script reads the user's information from AD builds a signature then saves it in Outlook under the user's email account.

I noticed when applying this to a new laptop that if the user has an Office 365 software license instead of a Home & Business / Pro license it is not saving the signature under the user's email account but instead saving it under signatures on this device.
Next week when I send out instructions to run the script with the updated Xmas information anyone who has O365 installed won't have their current signature updated as it will create a new signature on this device instead of updating the one on the email account.

The script has 3 sections of code.

The first part finds the Outlook software.

```
'Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
DEBUGMODEON = FALSE 'USED FOR FAULT FINDING AND DEBUGGING, SET TO FALSE FOR PRODUCTION USE

booLocksig = TRUE ' USED TO PREVENT USER FROM CHANGING SIGNATURE

'FIRST CHECK TO SEE IF OUTLOOK IS INSTALLED.  IF SO RECORD THE VERSION, IF NOT ALERT THE USER AND QUIT
If AppPathExist("outlook.exe") Then
    If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "Outlook is installed, version is: " & GetVersion("outlook.exe")
    End if
    strOutlookVer = GetVersion("outlook.exe")
else
    WScript.Echo "Outlook has not been detected.  Quitting!"
    WScript.Quit
end if

'GET FILE PATH FOR COMMON USE APPS
Function AppPathExist(sProgram) 
    sAppPathsBase = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" 
    sAppPathExe = RegRead(sAppPathsBase & sProgram & "\") 
    If sAppPathExe <> "" Then 
        AppPathExist = True 
    Else 
        AppPathExist = False 
    End If 
End Function 

'PULL VERSION FROM EXE
Function GetVersion(sProgram) 
    GetVersion = "Unknown" ' init value 
    sAppPathsBase = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" 
    sFilePath = RegRead(sAppPathsBase & sProgram & "\") 
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    If oFSO.FileExists(sFilePath) Then 
        sFileVer = oFSO.GetFileVersion(sFilePath) 
        If sFileVer <> "" Then 
            aFileVer = Split(sFileVer, ".") 
            GetVersion = aFileVer(0) 
        End If 
    End If 
End Function 

'REGISTRY READING FUNCTION
Function RegRead(sRegValue) 
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    On Error Resume Next 
    RegRead = oShell.RegRead(sRegValue) 
    ' If the value does not exist, error is raised 
    If Err Then 
        RegRead = "" 
        Err.clear 
    End If 
    ' If a value is present but uninitialized the RegRead method 
    ' returns the input value in Win2k. 
    If VarType(RegRead) < vbArray Then 
        If RegRead = sRegValue Then 
            RegRead = "" 
        End If 
    End If 
    On Error Goto 0 
End Function 

'IF DEBUG MODE ON THEN REPORT OUTLOOK DETECTION AS COMPLETE
If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "Outlook Detection Complete"
End if
```

The second part deals with getting information out of our AD. I am omitting that part.

The final section creates the signature.

```
' This section creates the signature files names and locations.
'====================
' Corrects Outlook signature folder location. Just to make sure that
' Outlook is using the purposed folder defined with variable : strFolderLocation
' Changing this in a production environmont might create extra work
' all employees are missing their old signatures
'====================
Dim objShell, RegKey, RegKeyParm
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & strOutlookVer & ".0\Common\General"
RegKey = RegKey & "\Signatures"
objShell.RegWrite RegKey , "Signatures"
strUserDataPath = ObjShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strFolderLocation = strUserDataPath &"\Microsoft\Signatures\"
strHtmFileString = strFolderLocation & strSignatureName & ".htm"

' This section checks if the signature directory exits and if not creates one.
'====================
Dim objFS1
Set objFS1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (objFS1.FolderExists(strFolderLocation)) Then
Else
    Call objFS1.CreateFolder(strFolderLocation)
End if

' The next section builds the signature file
'====================
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile,afile
Dim aQuote
aQuote = chr(34)

' This section builds the HTML file version
'====================
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' This section deletes to other signatures.
' These signatures are automaticly created by Outlook 2003.
'====================
Set AFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFolderLocation & strSignatureName & ".rtf")
aFile.Delete
Set AFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFolderLocation & strSignatureName & ".txt")
aFile.Delete

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strHtmFileString,True)
objFile.Close
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strHtmFileString, 2)

If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "objFile = " & objFile.Path &vbcrlf & "strFullName = " & strFullName &vbcrlf & "Writing HTML to File."
End if


'I HAVE REMOVED A LARGE SECTION OF CODE HERE BUT THIS WAS JUST CREATING OUR SIGNATURE IN HTML


If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "HTML File Generated"
End if
' ===========================
' This section readsout the current Outlook profile and then sets the name of the default Signature
' ===========================
' Use this version to set all accounts
' in the default mail profile
' to use a previously created signature
If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "Attempting to Set Default Signature"
End if
Call SetDefaultSignature(strSignatureName,"")

' Use this version (and comment the other) to
' modify a named profile.
'Call SetDefaultSignature _
' ("Signature Name", "Profile Name")

Sub SetDefaultSignature(strSigName, strProfile)
    
    dim objReg
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    strComputer = "."
    If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
        WScript.Echo "Checking if Outlook is running"
    End if
    If Not IsOutlookRunning Then
        If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
            WScript.Echo "Outlook isn't running"
        End if
        Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
        strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\"
        ' get default profile name if none specified
        If strProfile = "" Then
            objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, "DefaultProfile", strProfile
        End If
        ' build array from signature name
        myArray = StringToByteArray(strSigName, True)
        strKeyPath = strKeyPath & strProfile &  "\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676"
        objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, arrProfileKeys
        For Each subkey In arrProfileKeys
            strsubkeypath = strKeyPath & "\" & subkey
            objReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strsubkeypath, "New Signature", myArray
            If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
                WScript.Echo "Add New Signature Option To registry: " & strsubkeypath
            End if
            'objReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
            'strsubkeypath, "Reply-Forward Signature", myArray
        Next
        
        if booLockSig <> FALSE Then
            If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
            WScript.Echo "Locking Signature"
            End if
            objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\MailSettings\NewSignature" , strSignatureName
        End if
        
        If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
            WScript.Echo "Preventing Outlook Embedding the Images: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & strOutlookVer & ".0\Outlook\Options\Mail\Send Pictures With Document=0"
        End if
        objReg.SetDWordValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Office\" & strOutlookVer & ".0\Outlook\Options\Mail\", "Send Pictures With Document" , "0"
    Else
        strMsg = "Please shut down Outlook before running this script."
        MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "Outlook Signature Generator"
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub

Function IsOutlookRunning()
    dim objWMIService
    strComputer = "."
    strQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
    For Each objProcess In colProcesses
        If UCase(objProcess.Name) = "OUTLOOK.EXE" Then
            IsOutlookRunning = True
        Else
            IsOutlookRunning = False
        End If
    Next
    
End Function

Public Function StringToByteArray(Data, NeedNullTerminator)
    Dim strAll
    strAll = StringToHex4(Data)
    If NeedNullTerminator Then
        strAll = strAll & "0000"
    End If
    intLen = Len(strAll) \ 2
    ReDim arr(intLen - 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(strAll) \ 2
        arr(i - 1) = CByte("&H" & Mid(strAll, (2 * i) - 1, 2))
    Next
    StringToByteArray = arr
End Function

Public Function StringToHex4(Data)
    ' Input: normal text
    ' Output: four-character string for each character,
    ' e.g. "3204" for lower-case Russian B,
    ' "6500" for ASCII e
    ' Output: correct characters
    ' needs to reverse order of bytes from 0432
    Dim strAll
    For i = 1 To Len(Data)
        ' get the four-character hex for each character
        strChar = Mid(Data, i, 1)
        strTemp = Right("00" & Hex(AscW(strChar)), 4)
        strAll = strAll & Right(strTemp, 2) & Left(strTemp, 2)
    Next
    StringToHex4 = strAll
End Function

If DEBUGMODEON <> FALSE Then
    WScript.Echo "Script Complete. Exiting"
End if
```

How do I amend this script so the Office 365 installs act normally when applying the signature?

Comment: Have you checked what went wrong? (run the script with DEBUGMODEON?) Have you checked if the regkey is valid for outlook 365?

Comment: The first `On Error Resume Next` is madness. Delete it.

Comment: Change `DEBUGMODEON = FALSE` to `DEBUGMODEON =TRUE ` to see the text in `WScript.Echo`.

Comment: Figure out the programming language and replace the vba tag.

Comment: Sorry, finally getting round to checking this its been a hectic few days.. @niton I have no idea what the programming language is. I havent wrote this script I have just inherited it, the only reason I added the vba tag is becasue the file calls istaelf a vbscript. I have set the script to true and it all runs ok, no errors, it looks like Outllook itself is putting the signature in the wrong place and not the script, no idea why this is only happening on machines with O365 installed and not the Home & Business installs.

Comment: @Shrotter I checked the regkey and its not there for O365, but its not there for any other installs either so I have no idea how to dela with that. When settting DEBUGMODEON to true all tasks proceed as usual, but its still putting the signature in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

So looks like this was an issue to do with O365 and roaming signatures, the fix was to add the following registry key to disable the function

Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key Path: Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Setup
Value Name: DisableRoamingSignaturesTemporaryToggle
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data:1